# Primitive Recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, fold

In [A tutorial on universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf) chapter 4.1, it states that this pattern of recursion

```
h y [] = f y
h y (x:xs) = g y x xs (h y xs)
```

is primitive recursion, but I don't understand why the pattern

```
h [] = v
h (x:xs) = g x (h xs)
```

is not primitive recursion according to the [definition of primitive recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition).
The value of `h y'` is still based on `h y` in the `h (x:xs) = g x (h xs)` if we let `y = xs` and `y' = x:xs`.

Comment: Where does chapter 4.1 say that your second example is not primitive recursive? It starts with your second example and then just generalizes it somewhat (by adding the extra `y` parameter) to get your first version. But I see no claim that only your first one uses primitive recursion.

Comment: @Cactus This pattern of recursion on lists is called primitive recursion (Kleene, 1952). I think I misunderstand what it means. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but that is **not** to be taken to mean that **only** your first example is called primitive recursion, **in contrast to** your second example (also, it's confusing to refer to your examples because you flipped their order compared to the tutorial...)

Comment: @Cactus The tutorial says "We will generalise this pattern of recursion to primitive recursion". This kind of implies that the original pattern is not primitive recursion.

Comment: Another question is why is that a generalise form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primitive recursion scheme is *parametric* on the choice of `f,g`

```
h y [] = f y
h y (x:xs) = g y x xs (h y xs)
```

That is, we are free to choose `f,g` as we want, and `h` will be defined through primitive recursion.

In particular, we can choose

```
f = \y -> v
g = \y x xs -> g' x z
```

where `g'` is any other function picked by us. We then get

```
h y [] = v
h y (x:xs) = g' x (h y xs)
```

Now, if we let

```
h' xs = h () xs
```

we fix the `y` argument to an immaterial value so to recover the function in the question. Pedantically, `h'` is not obtained directly as an instance of the general form, so `h'` is technically not defined through the primitive recursion scheme seen above (i.e., it is not an instance of that). Sometimes, instead of `y` we find there many variables `y1 .. yn` allowing us to pick `n=0` and remove the `y` as we want in this case.

Comment: Well, you compare the general scheme and the desired goal and try to instantiate the parameters so that they match. A bit of trial and error may be needed.

Comment: According to [primitive recursive definition](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/COURSES/452/S14/dec.pdf), I think the general scheme should be `h y (x:xs) = g y xs (h y xs)` , but why in [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf) defines it as `h y (x:xs) = g y x xs (h y xs)` ?

Comment: @Sid The first definition of primitive recursion only considers natural numbers as arguments. When dealing with lists, it has to be extended. If we extend it as you propose, then `h y (x:xs)` can not depend on `x`, which is very restrictive: we can't access any of the list elements!